# apt-get install [pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 ... pkgn] not installing all items

Tags: apt, bash

I have a bash file with a list of packages to install for a new Ubuntu installation using apt install however, not all the packages in the list are installing. Repos are included in the script as necessary.

I've tried the 2 methods below:

> Method 1:

```
apt install [pkg1] [pkg2] [pkg3] ... [pkgn]
```

> Method 2 - (pseudo code):

```
String pkgs_list[] = {"pkg1" "pkg2" "pkg3" "pkgn"}
for each pkg in pkg_list {
  if pkg exists then {
    "do nothing"
  else
    apt install pkg
  }
}
```

Here is the complete bash code:

```
#***********************#
#***      Keys       ***#
#***********************#
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
wget -O - https://dl.sinew.in/keys/enpass-linux.key | apt-key add -
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | apt-key add -


#***********************#
#***   Repositories  ***#
#***********************#
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
echo "deb http://repo.sinew.in/ stable main" > \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/gnome3  #This is for gnome tweak tool extensions (source: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Themes-on-Ubuntu-with-Gnome-Tweak-Tool)
add-apt-repository -y ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
add-apt-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/

apt -y update

#WinHQ enables 32bit architecture
dpkg --add-architecture i386 

#***********************#
#***   apt install   ***#
#***********************#

#apt -y install \
#  nemo \
#  google-chrome-stable \
#  notepadqq dconf-editor \
#  nfs-common \
#  enpass \
#  virtualbox \
#  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso \
#  gnome-tweak-tool \
  #gnome-shell-extensions-user-themes \
#  vlc \
#  gimp \
#  winehq-stable \
#  synaptic

declare -a alist=("nemo"
  "google-chrome-stable"
  "notepadqq"
  "dconf-editor"
  "nfs-common"
  "enpass"
  "virtualbox"
  "virtualbox-guest-additions-iso"
  "gnome-tweak-tool"
  "vlc"
  "gimp"
  "winehq-stable"
  "synaptic"
  "usb-creator-gtk"
  "libreoffice"
  "chromium-browser"
  "thunderbird"
  "shotwell"
  "gnome-calendar")

for application in "${alist[@]}"
do
  dpkg -l $application
  if [ $? = '0' ]; then
    echo "***************************************************************************"
    echo "*****Application "$application" package is installed, no action taken.*****"
    echo "***************************************************************************"
  elif [ $? = '1' ]; then
    echo "******************************************"
    echo "*****Installing package $application.*****"
    echo "******************************************"
    #Add an if to match dock favorites and add to the dock .desktop file
    apt install $application -y
  fi
done
```

Here's the list of applications and there status after the script ran:

1. nemo                            - **ok**
2. google-chrome-stable            - **ok**
3. notepadqq                       - **did not install**
4. dconf-editor                    - **ok**
5. nfs-common                      - **did not install**
6. enpass                          - **ok**
7. virtualbox                      - **ok**
8. virtualbox-guest-additions-iso  - **don't know**
9. gnome-tweak-tool                - **did not install**
10. vlc                            - **ok**
11. gimp                           - **did not install**
12. winehq-stable                  - **did not install**
13. synaptic                       - **did not install**
14. usb-creator-gtk                - **did not install**
15. libreoffice                    - **ok**
16. chromium-browser               - **did not install**
17. thunderbird                    - **did not install**
18. shotwell                       - **did not install**
19. gnome-calendar                 - **did not install**

I can provide more information for each package is needed.

Thanks for your help.

> EDIT

The log file generated by using the command `$ sudo ./my_script.sh >> my_script.log` is to large so I will post what I think is the problem and we can go from there.

Below is the output for gimp, one that did not install. When my code checks if the package is installed by using the command `dpkg -l [package_name]` it returns the following when checking for gimp and the others.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  gimp           <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

ALL the packages that did not install return this with Version and Architecture as `<none>` which tells me there's no package install, right?  But when the bash script runs, the command return '0' making my statements believe the package is installed which does not seem to be the case according to dpkg.  Instead, dpkg is supposed to return something like this: ...

```
$ dpkg -l package

dpkg-query: no packages found matching package
```

... when a package` is not installed.

I don't understand what is happening here with `dpkg` returning the information posted.  What does this mean?  What's happening?

Thanks,

> EDIT

Additionally, if I try to remove the package with `apt` I get:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove gimp
[sudo] password for alex2wr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gimp' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please provide the actual output of your script.

Comment: I added more information to the question with part of the log of what I think is the problem.  It was too long to post. Let me know what else I can help with. Thanks.

Comment: If it's too long, post it on https://paste.ubuntu.com. That said, I don't see any relevent output from the script you posted. Just the output of some commands you ran afterwards, which are largely irrelevant.

Comment: Here's the log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R5XT6mc2yT/

Comment: (a) 18.04 is still in development and off-topic here. (b) Many PPAs do not support 18.04, so `apt -y update` likely did not run successfully and so the package lists might be inconsistent. (c) `dpkg -l`'s exit status is not an indicator of whether the package is installed or not, it merely shows whether `dpkg` *knows* about the package or not.

Comment: My appologies by posting about 18.04 however, the problem also happens in 17.10.   Regarding `dpkg -l`, thank you for clarifiyng that, I never fully understood why people use it.  Back to the problem, even if I don't use `dpkg -l` and just list the packages, like the current commended section in my script above, those packages still dont install.  Let me run it on a VM and generate a new log.

Comment: ...but yes I did notice 18.04 not being supported when reading the log posted.. it passes as Bionic

Comment: If you do run on 17.10, use `sudo ./my_script.sh > my_script.log  2>&1` so that both stderr and stdout are in the log, please.

Comment: Hello muru, I got to run the script on a VM running 17.10  like you specified above.  These are the packages that din't install - nfs-common, gnome-tweak-tool, gimp, winehq-stable, synaptic, chromium-browser.  And here is the log https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cFSSW7fMTK/

Comment: The command for getting the Wine repo key is incorrect. As for the rest, I have already told you the exit status of `dpkg` is not an indicator of the installation status.

Comment: Ahh , I see what I did wrong with Wine, I'll fix that.  As for the others, I understand dpkg is not a good indicator of the package being installed, I fully agree but....  even when using the command the simple way e.g. "apt install pack1 pack2 pack3 ... packn,"  those packages still don't install.

Comment: then you'll have to provide the output of `apt install pack1 ...`

Comment: Muru, I haven't forgotten about this issue, but I've been having other issues and had to put this one aside.  I can tell you that I am still having issues with the script.  The apt install [pkgs] still behaving in a way I don't understand.  So I gave up with bash and moved to Python.  I'll come back and post update when I figure it out.

Comment: @Thufir, why check if the package is already installed ? if you need them installed, why not simply install the package, even if it is already installed ? apt /apt-get would just skip it, as it is already installed ? no harm done..